# how to show a video inside the panel of my aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, video-streaming, flashplayer-10

I have an web application in which after login , in my dashboard page, i want to show the video of some promotions on which i have the video in my desktop.

in the aspx page, I have a panel and inside that i have to show the video.

```
<asp:Content ID="DashboardHeadContent" runat="server" 
ContentPlaceHolderID="DashboardHeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="MainContent" runat="server" 
ContentPlaceHolderID="DashboardMainContent">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="div1" style="overflow: auto">
         <asp:Panel ID="panelUpdateProgress" runat="server" 
         CssClass="updateProgress">

             // I need put the video here to play

         </asp:Panel>
         </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

As am new to this video play in the aspx page, Kindly help me on this.

Comment: You can use `<video>` tag to show stored video in ASPX page with HTML5, and you need clear path of `source` & set `type` depending on extension. If the video is in SWF format, use `<embed>` tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use html5 video tag to display video in asp.net

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

You can check out all the attributes available for video tag here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Comment: If we use this, it is downloading instead of playing